# macos: how to use CLion for caffe?

Tags: c++, macos, caffe

**use gcc to compile is ok:**

> gcc -o test_blob test_blob.cpp -D CPU_ONLY -lcaffe -lstdc++ -lglog

**but at CLion, got this error:**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "caffe::Blob<float>::mutable_cpu_data()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "caffe::Blob<float>::Reshape(int, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "google::LogMessage::stream()", referenced from:
      caffe::Blob<float>::LegacyShape(int) const in main.cpp.o
      caffe::Blob<float>::offset(int, int, int, int) const in main.cpp.o
      caffe::Blob<float>::CanonicalAxisIndex(int) const in main.cpp.o
  "google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int, google::CheckOpString const&)", referenced from:
      caffe::Blob<float>::LegacyShape(int) const in main.cpp.o
      caffe::Blob<float>::offset(int, int, int, int) const in main.cpp.o
      caffe::Blob<float>::CanonicalAxisIndex(int) const in main.cpp.o
  "google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()", referenced from:
      caffe::Blob<float>::LegacyShape(int) const in main.cpp.o
      caffe::Blob<float>::offset(int, int, int, int) const in main.cpp.o
      caffe::Blob<float>::CanonicalAxisIndex(int) const in main.cpp.o
  "google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::ForVar2()", referenced from:
      std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >* google::MakeCheckOpString<int, int>(int const&, int const&, char const*) in main.cpp.o
  "google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString[abi:cxx11]()", referenced from:
      std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >* google::MakeCheckOpString<int, int>(int const&, int const&, char const*) in main.cpp.o
  "google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::CheckOpMessageBuilder(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >* google::MakeCheckOpString<int, int>(int const&, int const&, char const*) in main.cpp.o
  "google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::~CheckOpMessageBuilder()", referenced from:
      std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >* google::MakeCheckOpString<int, int>(int const&, int const&, char const*) in main.cpp.o
  "caffe::Blob<float>::sumsq_data() const", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "caffe::Blob<float>::cpu_data() const", referenced from:
      caffe::Blob<float>::data_at(int, int, int, int) const in main.cpp.o
  "caffe::Blob<float>::asum_data() const", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [caffe] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [caffe] Error 2
```

---

here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)  
 project(caffe) set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11") set(USE_libstdcpp:BOOL false) 
 set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/bin/") 
 set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp) 
 add_executable(caffe ${SOURCE_FILES}) 
 target_compile_definitions(caffe PUBLIC CPU_ONLY=on)
```

---

**what should I edit CMakeLists.txt?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your CMake project is very different than the `gcc` compilation. I'll try to reconcile the two.

First, the `-l` flag for `gcc` refers to the libraries that should be linked to the executable after compiling. The CMakeLists.txt file should also link those libraries. Your executable should really be `test_blob` and your project cannot be named `caffe` because you are using the `caffe` library. The CMakeLists.txt should be of this form:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)          # using modern CMake
project(blob)                                # names your project 

find_package(glog)                           # finds your installation of glog
find_package(caffe)                          # finds your installation of caffe

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)                   # sets the "-std=c++11" flag
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/bin/") 

set(SOURCE_FILES test_blob.cpp) 
add_executable(test_blob ${SOURCE_FILES})    # creates the executable
target_link_libraries(test_blob glog caffe)  # links the test_blob target to glog and caffe
target_compile_definitions(test_blob PUBLIC CPU_ONLY=on)
```

This should fix your linker error.

Comment: @Jiahua you should make this the accepted answer so that people know it solved the problem

Comment: yes, thank for the reminder,  the first time I used stackoverflow to ask question.